# How to call a function with specific data structure in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have this function which calculates the add

```
data Expr
  = Num Double
  | Add Expr Expr
  | Sub Expr Expr
  deriving (Show)



  eval :: Expr -> Maybe Double
    eval (Num a) = if a < 0 then 
    eval (Add a b) = case eval a 
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just a1 -> case eval b of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just b1 -> Just (a1 + b1)
```

while calling it like this, it returns error:

> eval Add (Expr(1), Expr(2))
>
> :30:20: error:
> Data constructor not in scope: Expr :: t1 -> b0

Comment: Is `eval (Num a)` supposed to return `Nothing` if `a < 0`? Otherwise (unless you plan to add division later), I don't see any reason for using `Maybe Double` as the return type instead of `Double`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Add (Expr(1), Expr(2))` is not an expression for an `Expr`. First of all you need `Num` to construct an `Expr`, not an `Expr` since that is a *type* constructor, not a *data constructor*:

```
Add (Num 1) (Num 2)
```

Furthermore there should be *no* comma between the two, and we need brackets to pass the entire `Expr` we need parenthesis around the entire `Add …` block, so:

```
eval (Add (Num 1) (Num 2))
```

In your `eval` function it looks like something is missing after the `if a < 0 then …`

You can also implement `eval (Add a b)` as:

```
eval :: Expr -> Maybe Double
eval (Num a) = if a < 0 then … else …
eval (Add a b) = (+) <$> eval a <*> eval b
```